# Pass value of one application to other package application in background like facebook & facebook messenger app

Tags: java, android, push-notification

I have two app **APP1(Package name-: com.abc.q)** and **APP2(Package name -:com.xyz.y)**  in APP1 there is an activity which will open another APP2 activity which has notification comes from parse.com .I actually want that whenever any APP2 gets the notification it should show "1" in APP1 in small red oval.In gist when **APP2** gets notification from parse.com it should show **red oval notification** in **APP1** in the activity which i have decided.

**APP1 Acivity**

**1.)gkk.java**

```
public class gkk extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer ourSong;
    private static final String TAG = "gkk";
    Button button;private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private WebView webView;
    private WebView webView1;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


        setContentView(R.layout.lgin);


        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView11);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new InsideWebViewClient());
        webView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView1.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());

        webView.loadUrl("www.xyz.comm");

        webView1.loadUrl("www.xyz.comm");


        ourSong=MediaPlayer.create(gkk.this, R.raw.rollver);
        FloatingActionButton fabButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this) 
        .withDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.float_button))
        .withButtonColor(Color.WHITE) 
        .withGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT) 
        .withMargins(0, 0, 12, 12) 
        //.withButtonSize(180)
        .create();
        fabButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                //Intent intent = new Intent(gkk.this,St.class);
                Intent intent = new Intent(gkk.this,LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition( R.anim.down, R.anim.toup );
            }
        });


        FloatingActionButton fabButton2 = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this) 
        .withDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.n19))
        .withButtonColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        .withGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT)
        .withMargins(0, 0, 12, 85)

        .create();

        fabButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.xyz.y");
                if (intent != null) {
                    // We found the activity now start the activity
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    // Bring user to the market or let them choose an app?
                    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + "com.package.name"));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        });

         webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
        webView1.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("fetching Notice's..");
        pDialog.show();

        addListenerOnButton();
        webView.setWebViewClient(new InsideWebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error1.html");
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        webView1.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                webView1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/notification.html");
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    public class InsideWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.endsWith(".pdf")) 
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));

            return true;
        }
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " +url); 
            if (pDialog.isShowing()) { pDialog.dismiss(); } }  }

    class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }}

 public void onLunchAnotherApp() {

        final String appPackageName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();

        Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(appPackageName);
        if (intent != null) {

            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);

        } else {

            onGoToAnotherInAppStore(intent, appPackageName);

        }

    }

    public void onGoToAnotherInAppStore(Intent intent, String appPackageName) {

        try {

            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cc.vv=en" + appPackageName));
            startActivity(intent);

        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {

            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName));
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    }

     public void addListenerOnButton() {

        final Context context = this;



        Button tut4= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button18);





    }



}
```

**APP2 Activity**

**2.)DBAdapter.java**

```
public class DBAdapter {


    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_MESSAGE = "message";


    public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_DATE, KEY_TITLE, KEY_MESSAGE };


    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbNotif";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "notif";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;  



    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_NAME + " (" + KEY_ROWID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_DATE
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_MESSAGE
            + " TEXT NOT NULL" + ");";


    private final Context context;


    private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;


    private SQLiteDatabase db;


    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
        myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }


    public DBAdapter open() {
        db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }


    public void close() {
        myDBHelper.close();
    }

    // insert data 
    public long insertNotif(String date, String title, String message) {
        long result = 0;

        open();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_DATE, date);
        cv.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        cv.put(KEY_MESSAGE, message);

        result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        close();

        return result;
    }



    public Cursor getAllNotif() {
        open();
        Cursor c = db.query(true, TABLE_NAME, ALL_KEYS, null, null, null,
                null, KEY_DATE + " DESC", null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        close();

        return c;
    }


    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
            _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);
        }


        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);


            onCreate(_db);
        }
    }
}
```

**3.)lgin.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dip" >



        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button18" >
        </WebView>



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button18"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#333366"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="37dip"
        android:text="xyz"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="19dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button18"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#333366" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/webView11qwd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button18"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/card_depth" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**4.)Main.java**

```
public class Main  extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String TAG = Main.class.getSimpleName();
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private DBAdapter db;
    private ListView list;
    private ListView listView;
    private List<Message> listMessages = new ArrayList<>();
    private MessageAdapter adapter;
    private PrefManager pref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

      setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        adapter = new MessageAdapter(this);
        pref = new PrefManager(getApplicationContext());

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String email = pref.getEmail();

        if (email != null) {
            ParseUtils.subscribeWithEmail(pref.getEmail());
        }else{
            Log.e(TAG, "Email is null. Not subscribing to parse!");
        }
        initView();
        setNotif();
    }
    private void initView() {

                this.db = new DBAdapter(this);

                this.list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    }


    private void setNotif() {

                Cursor cNotif = db.getAllNotif();

        if (cNotif.getCount() > 0) {

                    String[] data = new String[] { DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID, DBAdapter.KEY_DATE, DBAdapter.KEY_TITLE, DBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE };

            int[] view = new int[] { R.id._id, R.id.date, R.id.title, R.id.message };
            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, cNotif,
                    data, view, SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
            this.list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

        Message m = new Message(message, System.currentTimeMillis());
        listMessages.add(0, m);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private class MessageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public MessageAdapter(Activity activity) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return listMessages.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return listMessages.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
            }

            TextView txtMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message);
            TextView txtTimestamp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);

            Message message = listMessages.get(position);
            txtMessage.setText(message.getMessage());

            CharSequence ago = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(message.getTimestamp(), System.currentTimeMillis(),
                    0L, DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL);

            txtTimestamp.setText(String.valueOf(ago));

            return view;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
            pref.logout();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

when there is a new notification in DBAdapter.java it should show notification oval in gkk.java of other package app activity.

Comment: You need to implement content provider for this.
Here are reference links http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/12/content-provider-in-android.html#.VpnfB1N97Vo

Comment: ok i think you are close ,i have to pass notification count for every app2 sqlite notification insert to other app1 like oval notification counter

Comment: Insert in db then then send broadcast using local broadcast manager saying data changed when you receive broadcast on other end request another query to get updated data

Comment: @sector11 could you please help that how to implement in above two codes which i provided.Pass value from DBAdapter.java on insertion to  gkk.java

Comment: Is this you actual code or you have something else. I mean since m free i can try because this scenario i have not tried before so will give it a try. Is this code fine?

Comment: What is you actual problem parse notification or local notification when db adapter data changes?

Comment: @sector11 my code is working fine i just have to pass the static like "1" from DBAdapter.java when there is insertion in sqlite then it should pass value "1" to gkk.java in any TextView.

Comment: @sector11 : It actually successfully inserting value in db on notification send from parse.com but i want when it inserted in db it should pass "1" to another app gkk.java in textview

Comment: i got now what you are actually trying to achieve

Comment: @sector11 yaa please help

Comment: have you solved this issue otherwise join chat room here on Stackoverflow??

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Content of GKK.java file should be. Note that i created new File just to check the flow. You can replace the content from this file inside you file where you wish to receive the notification. Note that from comments i used sendBroadcast instead of LocalBroadcastManager because you are sending notification across different application. So just to check whether all was working fine or now run this command from terminal

adb shell am broadcast -a in.ashish29agre.stackoverflow.retrofit.appnotify.NEW_ROW_INSERTED

```
  package in.ashish29agre.notificationreceverapp;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String NOTIFICATION_ACTION = "in.ashish29agre.stackoverflow.retrofit.appnotify.NEW_ROW_INSERTED";
    private NotificationBroadcastReceiver receiver;
    private IntentFilter filter;
    private TextView notificationStatusTv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        receiver = new NotificationBroadcastReceiver();
        filter = new IntentFilter(NOTIFICATION_ACTION);
        notificationStatusTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.notification_status_tv);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    private class NotificationBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(NOTIFICATION_ACTION)) {
                if (intent.hasExtra("VALUE")) {
                    notificationStatusTv.setText("" + intent.getIntExtra("VALUE", -1));
                } else {
                    notificationStatusTv.setText("Notification received successfully with no data");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="in.ashish29agre.notificationreceverapp.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notification_status_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tye this is in terminal to check notification\nadb shell am broadcast -a in.ashish29agre.stackoverflow.retrofit.appnotify.NEW_ROW_INSERTED" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is you new updated DBAdapter.java

```
package in.ashish29agre.stackoverflow.retrofit.appnotify;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter {

    public static final String NOTIFICATION_ACTION = "in.ashish29agre.stackoverflow.retrofit.appnotify.NEW_ROW_INSERTED";

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_MESSAGE = "message";


    public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_DATE, KEY_TITLE, KEY_MESSAGE };


    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbNotif";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "notif";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;  



    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_NAME + " (" + KEY_ROWID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_DATE
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_MESSAGE
            + " TEXT NOT NULL" + ");";


    private final Context context;


    private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;


    private SQLiteDatabase db;


    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
        myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }


    public DBAdapter open() {
        db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }


    public void close() {
        myDBHelper.close();
    }

    // insert data 
    public long insertNotif(String date, String title, String message) {
        long result = 0;

        open();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_DATE, date);
        cv.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        cv.put(KEY_MESSAGE, message);

        result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        close();

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(NOTIFICATION_ACTION);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("VALUE", 1);
        context.sendBroadcast(notificationIntent);
        Log.d("NOTIFICATION", "Broadcast sent");
        return result;
    }



    public Cursor getAllNotif() {
        open();
        Cursor c = db.query(true, TABLE_NAME, ALL_KEYS, null, null, null,
                null, KEY_DATE + " DESC", null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        close();

        return c;
    }


    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
            _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);
        }


        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);


            onCreate(_db);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100847/discussion-on-answer-by-sector11-pass-value-of-one-application-to-other-package).